# Laravel GroupBy and display in blade with multiple foreach'es

Tags: laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I am thinking how to write smartest this code:

Controller:

```
$tasks = Task::where('department', '=', $department)
->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
->get();
```

In blade file I write:

```
@foreach($tasks as $task)
@if($task->status == 1)
<tr>
    <td class="cell">#{{ $task->id }}</td>
    <td class="cell">{{ $task->title }}</td>
</tr>
@endif
@endforeach

LOT OF HTML

@foreach($tasks as $task)
@if($task->status == 2)
<tr>
    <td class="cell">#{{ $task->id }}</td>
    <td class="cell">{{ $task->title }}</td>
</tr>
@endif
@endforeach
```

Is it possible to foreach not all elements, but only with $task->status == 1 ? then only $task->status == 2 and etc? Because there will be very long loops with unwanted statuses. I think that it is possible to do with GroupBy function, but do not find the way. Examples I found on the internet do not fit my requirements.

P.S. The best would be to use forelse instead foreach to display information when sector is empty, but in this way I get a lot of bigger code than usual.

Please offer me shortest and most traffic-friendly method

Comment: You can simply add another ordeyBy function on status so it wil sort therecord by status as well.
$tasks = Task::where('department', '=', $department)
->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
->orderBy('status', 'ASC')
->get();

Answer (score 1):

You can simply fetch status in array and use loop to display status wise record in blade file like first table display record of status 1 and so on.

```
 $tasks = Task::where('department', '=', $department) 
 ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
 ->get();

 //Fetch Status in another varibale
 $status = Task::distinct()->orderBy('status')->pluck('status');
 
 @foreach ($status as $st)
  <table>   
    @foreach($tasks as $task)
        @if ($task->status === $st)
            <tr>
               <td class="cell">#{{ $task->id }}</td>
               <td class="cell">{{ $task->title }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endif
    @endforeach
  </table>   
 @endforeach
```

Comment: but is it possible to choose which status records to display in @foreach ? because there will be multiple tables and different statuses should be displayed in different <table> ... </table>

Comment: So do you want to display status wise record in different table ? Like first table for status 1 and second for 2 etc..?

Comment: I guess that is something interesting what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create two different variables. like this.

```
$firstTasks = Task::where('department', $department)
->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
->where('status', 1)
->get();

$secondTasks = Task::where('department', $department)
->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
->where('status', 2)
->get();
```

Comment: I did like this from start, but thought that smart php algorithm is better than additional database access, but I guess there is no smart algorithm in this case